# VBA Powerpoint Macro: Run in background

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Can a macro run in the background whilst the user is using the presentation?

For example, some sort of auto-correct function or auto-format function>

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "using the presentation" - do you refer to editing or presenting?

Comment: Right. So I guess my example would be editing. But I suppose I'd be interested in knowing if its possible for during presentation as well.  Perhaps something like changing the colour of text when the cursor is over it. This can probably done another way but its just an example of the type of thing I'm talking about.

Comment: @JoshDG - Added a small demo of the possibilities. However, I don't recommend having some code running for a presentation. There is really no need for it as PPT itself gives you enough interactive tools to make your presentation ... dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

This is very much possible. I have created a small demo to show how it can be done.

[image]

In this demo, I have placed a command button and whenever it is clicked (in presentation mode), it displays a message.

Answer (score 0):

If I really needed to do something like this for some reason, I would probably add a form, put any code that needs to run concurrently in the form, have it run as part of the form's initialization subroutine, then from the main body of code, call the form modelessly.